# Unable to connect to server: timeout expired

Tags: database, postgresql, server, digital-ocean, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connect to the server's Postgres database with pgadmin.

`pg_hba.conf`:

[image: My pg_hba.conf configuration]

`postgresql.conf`:

[image: postgresql.conf configuration]

Connection with pgAdmin:

[image: Connection with pgadmin]

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Please paste the files here, instead of images

Comment: It isn't getting far enough to care about pg_hba.conf.  Look at the firewall.